# MySQL, check if result has value, if not take another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table structure like this:

```
Page_id  || type  ||  user_id
1            1           0
2            2           0
3            3           0
4            1           1
5            2           1
6            3           1
```

From this table I would like to get page_id 4,5 and 6.

But I can also have table data like this

```
Page_id  || type  ||  user_id
1            1           0
2            2           0
3            3           0
4            1           1
5            2           1
```

Then I would like to get page_id 4, 5 and 3.

So I have to get all the types, but with the priority user_id and if there is no record with user_id 1, then take the one with 0

Have tried a lot. I know I can sort it with PHP, but I hope there is a way with MySQL.

Regards Andreas

//////// ANSWER /////////
I got a lot of suggestions, and I haven't tried them all, so I can't tell it they where right or not. But I have accepted an answer, which worked for me.Thank to everybody.

Comment: `SELECT page_id FROM TABLE WEHERE user_id <> 0`?

Comment: *"Have tried a lot."* Can you show us?

Comment: What does `user_id=0` stand for?

Comment: *"Gets all types, but only one of them, would like to get 1, 2 and 4"* - sorry, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @MarkBaker *whispering* where _userid_ <>0 ;-)

Comment: @halfbit <whisper>thanks</whisper>

Comment: Can see that my question is poor. So have tried to edit it to make i more clear what I want.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - the things I have tried is with php and arrays, but I dont like this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Type, a.Page_ID
FROM   table a
         INNER JOIN
       (SELECT    Type, MAX(User_ID) AS User_ID
        FROM      table
        GROUP BY  Type ) b
       ON a.Type = b.Type AND a.User_ID = b.User_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a `SELECT` query as follow

```
SELECT Page_id 
FROM table
WHERE user_id != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36161/1/0) demonstrates the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(
  SELECT s1.Page_id 
  FROM myTable AS s1 
  WHERE m.type = s1.type
  ORDER BY s1.Page_id 
  LIMIT 1
) AS PageID, type, 
(
  SELECT s2.user_id 
  FROM myTable AS s2 
  WHERE m.type = s2.type
  ORDER BY s2.Page_id 
  LIMIT 1
) AS User
FROM myTable AS m
```

The results are the records where `Page_id` is 1, 2, and 4.  As you can see in both of the sub queries I am ordering by `Page_id` to make sure the data is pulled from the same record and the first `Page_id` for that occurrence of the `type` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

To return only one record unique to a couple columns, you'll want to use the GROUP BY statement.  Then for any other column outside of the group by columns, you need to pick an aggregate function so it knows how to summarize the value if it finds multiple records in that group.  In this case you want non-zero, so max() would work

```
SELECT type, max(user_id) as user_id
  FROM table
 GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

how about that?

```
select page_id,type from (
select page_id,type, user_id from mytable 
group by page_id,type, user_id having user_id=max(user_id)
 ) as x where user_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Will there ever be multiple rows for a page where user_id is not zero?  Because if not (if at most you only have one row per page where user_id = 1) then this will work:

```
SELECT ifNull(t1.page_id,t2.page_id) as page_id, t1.type,
       CASE WHEN t2.page_id IS NULL THEN t1.user_id ELSE t2.user_id END as user_id
       #start with all rows (including duplicates)
  FROM myTable t1
       #look for a user_id > 0 for this type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.type = t2.type AND t2.user_id > 0
 WHERE t2.page_id IS NULL # if no record with user_id > 0 found, then no need to filter
       # if a record with user_id > 0 was found, then filer out the user_id = 0 record
    OR (t2.page_id IS NOT NULL AND t1.user_id > 0)
```

See in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba877/5